# General equation of a roulette

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

Currently I am trying to derive the equations x and y shown in the attached picture. I am struggling to find the horizontal and vertical components of lines u and v with angle phi and phi one. Could someone suggest a hint please? [image]

Comment: Law of gearing in mechanical design, general involutes ...

Comment: I meant more of a mathematical hint thanks anyhow

Comment: If you go through the theory of gears without slipping there are considerations of equal arc lengths, so that $ s=R_1 \theta_1=R_2 \theta_2$ etc.